# Specifying Etag or Expiry date in HTML

Tags: html, http-headers

I have a pure HTML website, and does not have access to the IIS server, its a basic site, now whenever I check the site Performance in the performance testing tools like (Pingdom Tools, GTMetrix, Google Insights etc).

It always says "Leverage browser caching", and this adversely affects my site performance

I did a lot of research for set the expiry date for the (css,js,images,html etc), but all shows the option with IIS. I am using Pure HTML with No Apache, No IIS, its a basic windows hosting provider.

Can anyone tell me the steps I can use to set the expiry headers of the above source from the HTML itself?

Comment: There must be *some* web server (HTTP server) software running, otherwise there is no web site. Consider posting the URL if you cannot deduce the server information on your own (servers normally announce themselves in HTTP headers).

Answer (score 2):

If the pages (from whatever type/extension) are static (not dynamic like PHP, ASP, etc.), the caching mechanism should be pretty automatic. The web server is supposed to add [Last-Modified or ETag headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) for you and the browser (or "user agent") is supposed to understand these.

You can check these headers are present or not with a tool such as [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (on Windows).

If they are not present, then you would have to use a [HTTP equivalent META tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp), like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="last-modified" content="Sun, 27 Jan 2012 11:52:12 GMT" />
```

Comment: Is there some evidence of `meta http-equiv="last-modified"` having any effect on anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use `meta`-Tags to set HTTP headers in the HTML:

`<meta http-equiv="foo" content="bar" />`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element#HTTP_message_headers

Comment: hi @markus unterwaditzer i have already used meta tag, here is how it looks like:
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="Wed, 01 Jan 2014">
does the ordering of the meta tags matters...

Comment: As far as i know, the real HTTP header gets preferred over the HTML tag. So you can't *override* a value with HTML.